# Addjust pointsize and add mean to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to improve my chart by doing two things. First, I want to add a point that contains the mean value for each variable. Second, I want to make the point size a function of how many times the value is actually present in each variable. If you have any other suggestions on how to make my graph clearer, pls to hesitate to propose them to me. Thank you a lot !

```
MD4_long <- MD4 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())  %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value) - 3,
         value = ifelse(value == 3, NA, value)) %>%
  group_by(name)


ggplot(MD4_long, aes(x = value, y = reorder(name, value))) +
  geom_point(aes (colour = value, size = 3)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = ~gsub("^.*_", "", .x)) +
  theme_light()+
  scale_colour_viridis_c(aesthetics = "colour")+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

```
structure(list(veränderung_imap_austausch.verstärkt.akteuren = structure(c(3L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_austausch.verstärkt.ideen = structure(c(5L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 6L, 
3L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_fortschritt.umsetzung = structure(c(4L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 6L, 
3L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_neue.strukturen = structure(c(4L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 5L, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 6L, 
1L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_zuständigkeiten.klarer = structure(c(3L, 
3L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 4L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_rollen.klarer = structure(c(3L, 
3L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, 4L, 1L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 4L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_digitale.lösungen = structure(c(4L, 
4L, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 
NA, 6L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, 1L, 5L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_klarheit.prozesse = structure(c(5L, 
3L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_weiterent.planung = structure(c(5L, 
3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_arbeit.relfelktieren = structure(c(4L, 
3L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_veranstaltung.ergebnisorientiert = structure(c(6L, 
4L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 6L, 6L, 
3L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_motivation = structure(c(5L, 4L, 
NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, 6L, 4L
), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_salienz = structure(c(3L, 4L, NA, 
NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", "Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", 
"k. A."), class = c("ordered", "factor")), veränderung_imap_interkult.öffnung = structure(c(3L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, NA, 3L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_austausch.kommunen.verstärkt = structure(c(4L, 
4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, NA, 2L, 6L, 
4L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_einarbeitung = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 6L, 6L, 4L
), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), veränderung_imap_einsatz.vielfalt.verstärkt = structure(c(3L, 
4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 6L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("Stimme nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Stimme teilweise zu", 
"Stimme zu", "Stimme voll zu", "k. A."), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -114L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to count the number of occurrences  of each category/value pair and use this in the `aes(size=)` function. You also need to calculate the mean of each value and the pass a second `geom_point()` to the graph.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyverse)

MD4_long <- MD4 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())  %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value) - 3,
         value = ifelse(value == 3, NA, value)) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
  

ggplot(MD4_long, aes(x = value, y = reorder(name, value))) +
  geom_point(aes (size = count)) +
  geom_point(aes (x = mean), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = ~gsub("^.*_", "", .x)) +
  theme_light()+
  scale_colour_viridis_c(aesthetics = "colour")+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is it possible to increase the size of the points proportionally ?

Comment: The size of the points are proportional to the number of times that each answer has been given. What do you mean exactly? Note that the legend points are larger due to the number of `NA`s for each category.

Comment: If it is possible to double the size of all points

Comment: In principle that's possible. I would however suggest to filter out the `NA` values, so that the points are more distinguishable. I have updated the solution.

Comment: If I just drop the NAs I lose a lot of data. So how can I just increase the size of the points?

Comment: You don't lose any data in removing the NAs. They are not included in your first plot neither. That being said, you can play with the size of the image when you save it and the points will change the relative size.